# Implementing Fanout in Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I am implementing a http server which fans out work to http clients using vertx version 3.5.4.

The server receives work and fans it out to a bunch of clients asynchronously. However, I need to block the request thread till all the results have arrived.

In a pure java world, i would do something like:

```
CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch( 3 ); 
executor.submit( new Request(client1) );
executor.submit( new Request(client2) );
executor.submit( new Request(client3) );
latch.await(); // block the request thread

//In callback thread from clients
latch.countdown();
```

However, in vertx, I can't block the main event-loop thread.
What is the recommended way to block the initial request thread?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sync/java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you must not block the event loop. In the asynchronous world, you need to compose the different results and eventually reply to the request.

Take a look at the [Concurrent composition](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_concurrent_composition) section of the docs.